# git project with 2branches and some different sources

Tags: git, github

hey i'm developing react native application with different source some library are works in android and some working in ios i want to install library and write some codes just for android that ios not using it i knew i cal split codes via Platform.OS but i just want have different branches
one branch for codes that share for android and ios project
second branch for the codes that only writes for android
third branch for the codes that only writes for ios

i'm new to git and reading documentation and not found anything thats help me to do this
the way i found is copy paste code and push to git for each branch but its not the true way to handle this

Comment: I am not sure branch is the best, split your code by directory and work on your build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a different approach by using [git submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/). It requires a little extra learning but it is worth it.

Basically, each submodule is a repository of its own that is embedded within another repository.

So for example, if I were you I would do the following:

1. Define three repositories: 'Android code' repository, 'iOS code' repository and 'Mutual Code' repository.
2. I would then embed the 'Mutual Code' repository as a submodule into both the 'Android code' and 'iOS code' repositories.
3. Now whatever you develop in the 'Mutual Code' repository can be easily updated within each of the other repositories.

I hope this helps.